# Geometric Numerical integration of a simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, control-theory, classical-mechanics

I have this 1D oscillator whose equations of motion is given by- $m \ddot{y}=-ky$ and when written is terms of conjugate variables $(p,q)$ in matrix form, we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{q} \\ \dot{p}\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{m} \\ -k &0
\end{bmatrix}}_{A}\begin{bmatrix}q \\ p\end{bmatrix}$$
Now the author have presented three approaches

(1) Explicit Euler : According to this form $x_{n+1}=x_n+h f(x_n)$ we have $$\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}\\ p_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{h}{m}\\-kh & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} q_n \\p_n \end{bmatrix}=\left(I+Ah \right)\begin{bmatrix}q_n \\p_n\end{bmatrix}$$

(2) Implicit Euler : with respect to the form $x_{n+1}=x_n+h f(x_{n+1})$ we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}\\ p_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{1+h^2\tfrac{k}{m}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{h}{m}\\-kh & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} q_n \\p_n \end{bmatrix}=\left(I-Ah \right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}q_n \\p_n\end{bmatrix}$$

(3) Symplectic Euler : The symplectic Euler VT
$$\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}\\ p_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}q_n+h \frac{p_{n+1}}{m} \\p_n-hkq_n \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1-h^2\frac{k}{m} & \frac{h}{m}\\-kh & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} q_n \\p_n \end{bmatrix}$$
and the symplectic Euler TV :
$$\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}\\ p_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}q_n+h \frac{p_{n}}{m} \\p_n-hkq_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{h}{m}\\-kh & 1-h^2\frac{k}{m} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} q_n \\p_n \end{bmatrix}$$
All of these are okay so far, now the author claims for following differential equations--

$(1)~~\dot{q}=p+\frac{h}{2}q~,~\dot{p}=-q+\frac{h}{2}p~~(2)~~ \dot{q}=p-\frac{h}{2}q~,~\dot{p}=-q+\frac{h}{2}p$

$(3)~~\dot{q}=p-\frac{h}{2}q~,~\dot{p}=-q-\frac{h}{2}p ~~(4)~~\dot{q}=p+\frac{h}{2}q~,~\dot{p}=-q-\frac{h}{2}p$

with $k=m=1$ the exact solutions of (1) and (3) will follow the numerical solutions obtained by explicit and implicit euler methods, and solutions of (2) and (4) follows the results of symplectic euler methods. I'm not able to understand from where the differential equations are arising and how their exact solutions replicate the numerical euler solutions ?

Comment: In the last list the labels (2) and (3) are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is indeed somewhat overreaching, you can at most claim that the distance from the solution of the modified system to the numerical solution  is one order more accurate than the error of the numerical method.

For the **explicit Euler method**, you get by comparing $x_{k+1}=x_k+f(x_k)h$ with the expansion of some other equation $\dot x=g_h(x)$ where $x_k$ corresponds to $x(t)$ and $x_{k+1}$ to $x(t+h)$
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+g_h(x(t))h+\frac12g_h'(x)g(x)h^2+O(h^3).
$$
Thus in first order $g_h(x)=f(x)+O(h)$ to capture the same main dynamic. Exhibiting the next order term we get $g(x)=f(x)+hu(x)+O(h^2)$. On the other hand for the equality of the Euler iteration and the exact solution we need
$$
f(x)=g_h(x)+\frac12g_h'(x)g(x)h+O(h^2).
$$
Now insert the ansatz $g=f+uh$ on the right side 
$$
f(x)=f(x)+u(x)h+\frac12(f'(x)+u'(x)h)(f(x)+u(x)h)h+O(h^2)\\
\\
\implies u(x)=-\frac12f'(x)f(x)
$$
in the terms linear in $h$, ignoring quadratic or higher degree terms.

Now in the present example with $f(x)=Ax$, we get $u(x)=-\frac12A^2x$.

As the **implicit Euler method** is the time reversed version of explicit Euler, you get $g_h(x)=f(x)+\frac12f'(x)f(x)h$ which implies that there is a sign error in the formulas you wrote down (more precisely, the case (3) formulas are for implicit Euler, switched with case (2)).

The computation for the **symplectic Euler methods** could follows similar lines, but is a bit more complicated. In the linear case it is easier to take the logarithm of the step matrix $\log(I+hB)=hB-\frac12h^2B^2+O(h^3)$. In the **case (3) VT** this gives
\begin{align}
B&=\begin{bmatrix}-h&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix},
\\
\log(I+hB)&=h\begin{bmatrix}-h&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}
    -\frac12h^2\begin{bmatrix}h^2-1&-h\\h&-1\end{bmatrix}+O(h^3)
\\
&=h\begin{bmatrix}-\frac h2&1\\-1&\frac h2\end{bmatrix}+O(h^3),
\end{align}
or $\dot q = p-\tfrac h2q$, $\dot p = -q+\tfrac h2 p$.

The **case (4) TV** is analogueous, here you just have to exchange $p$ and $q$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. one doubt, when you're writing $u(x)=-\tfrac{1}{2}f'(x)f(x)$ , are you considering $h \to 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, or just take the linear coefficients and arrange that their total is zero, so the remaining terms are all $O(h^2)$.

Comment: I still have some doubts here. i'll go step by step, so for the system $\dot{x}=g_h(x)$, you have written a taylor expansion, from where we intend to find $g_h(x)$ by comparing coefficients with $x_{k+1}=x_k+f(x_k)h$ where $x_k$ is the numerical solution and $x(t)$ would be the exact solution, but it's correct upto a certain order so you have introduced a perturbation to the vector field, and the new field is $g=f+u(x)h$ here $u(x)$ is the perturbation right ? also $g$ and $g_h$ are different right ? and how did you get the equality $f(x)=f(x)+u(x)h+\cdots$ ? here $f(x)=Ax$ what is g_h(x) ?

Comment: And i don't see where the comparison comes into play , and how do i get $g_h(x)=f(x)-\frac{1}{2}f'(x)f(x)h$ ?

Comment: So , for the new function $g$ shouldn't it be like $x \mapsto g(x):=f(x)+u(x)h$ so we have $g(x)=g(x)+\tfrac{1}{2}g'(x)g(x)+O (h^2) \implies f(x)+u(x)h=(f(x)+u(x)h)+\tfrac{1}{2}(f'(x)+hu'(x))(f(x)+hu(x))h+O(h^2)$ .                            
 i'm sure i'm missing something? it's a little confusing with all the $f$'s and $g$'s.

Comment: No, your $f(x_k)$ from the Euler method has to coincide with the $g_h(x(t))+\frac h2 g'(x(t))g(x(t))+...$ from the Taylor expansion. To get $x_k=x(t_k)+O(h^p)$, you need also equality up to $O(h^p)$ in the identity of the slopes. Thus if you want to go one step further, you get with $g_h=g_0+g_1h+g_2h^2+...$ to annihilate linear and quadratic terms in $$f=g_0+g_1h+g_2h^2+\frac h2(g'_0+g'_1h)(g_0+g_1h)+\frac{h^2}6(g_0''[g_0,g_0]+g_0'^2g_0)$$ so that again $g_0=f$, $g_1=-\frac12f'f$ and newly $g_2=\frac13f'^2f+\frac1{12}f''[f,f]$.

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated. This makes sense now.